# Using WinApi invocation to set mask property masked text control from another program

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to change the mask property in editMask control in vb6 with another program using WinApi function or message and can't find a message that do it.

what WinApi message is used when the mask is set?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> What Winapi message is used when the mask is set?

A masked edit is not a Windows control. Windows `EDIT` controls do not offer mask functionality. If you are going to influence this from outside you will first need to know exactly what this control is. After that, it's likely that you would need to inject into the target application in order to make the change. That is, assuming that the target application does not support enough automation to avoid such egregious hacking.

Comment: It is an ActiveX control located in MSMASK32.OCX file.  I want to make a tool for my application application .

Comment: In that case you will need to inject into the process so that you can run your code in the process.